# How python project can download all dependencies by itself?

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, dependencies, external-dependencies

I am given a project in a college. The task is to create automated test suite for a web application feature. The automation project will generate report fo the tests. I will use selenium for the project. The task requires that "no dependencies" should be added manually when running the project on another machine. All dependencies should be inside the project or installed by project itself. I didn't understand how it can be possible. Well, I can make a requirements.txt file and the user can use a single pip command to install all dependencies, however, it is also considered "adding manually". How the project itself can install all dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add all the requirements using the "pip freeze" in the requirements.txt file and then you can add this line of code in your main file like.

```
import os

os.system('pip install -r requirements.txt')
```